# Authenticate and authorize SOAP, Grails, CXF

Tags: grails, soap, cxf

I'm working on a Grails project that needs to authenticate the user calling my SOAP service.

For the authentication, I'm using CXF and it's working fine, but when I have to authorize using `@PreAuthorize` with my own implementation of `org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator`, the user received by my implementation of `PermissionEvaluator` is `grails.anonymous.user` instead of the user authorized by CXF.

How can I get the user authorized by CXF in my implementation of `org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to setup the security context in SecurityContextHolder, @see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html